# install MongoDB C++ Driver problem in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongo-cxx-driver

I want to install MongoDB C++ Driver, so first is mongocxx

I follow this installation:
http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/
but I can not pass step 4

when I run this in mongo-cxx-driver/build

```
sudo cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

it shows

```
-- Auto-configuring bsoncxx to use MNMLSTC for polyfills since C++17 is inactive
CMake Error at src/mongocxx/CMakeLists.txt:37 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findlibmongoc-1.0.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "libmongoc-1.0", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libmongoc-1.0"
  (requested version 1.13.0) with any of the following names:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    libmongoc-1.0Config.cmake
    libmongoc-1.0-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "libmongoc-1.0" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "libmongoc-1.0_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "libmongoc-1.0" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
```

second question,
Step 2: Choose a C++17 polyfill how can I set MNMLSTC/core?

does anyone can help me,I already trap here for a long time ?

my env:
mongo-c-driver 1.15.1
libmongoc-1.0
mongocxx-3.4.x

Answer (score 0):

Cmake is complaining about not finding a package configuration file (xxx.cmake), probably because you didn't build libmongoc/libbson.

I've tried to reproduce your issue and hit the same problem when I only installed them (apt-get install), so my suggestion is that you get the sources and build them as described at: http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html

Here's the list of commands (with the latest version of mongo-c-driver=1.15.1) which I just tried and worked fine:

```
wget https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases/download/1.15.1/mongo-c-driver-1.15.1.tar.gz
tar xzf mongo-c-driver-1.15.1.tar.gz
cd mongo-c-driver-1.15.1
mkdir cmake-build
cd cmake-build
cmake -DENABLE_AUTOMATIC_INIT_AND_CLEANUP=OFF ..
make
sudo make install
```

At this point you can go back into mongocxx/build and run again the command you were stuck at:

```
cd ../../mongo-cxx-driver/build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```